# install through swift package manager

Tags: xcode, swift, postgresql, swift2, xcode7.3

i want to install the below app

https://github.com/stepanhruda/PostgreSQL-Swift/blob/master/Readme.md

but i am in darkness how to do it or what is the location of package.swift file in my pc or how to use swift package manager.i have go through this link

https://swift.org/package-manager/#example-usage

i am using

```
xcode 7.3 and swift 2.2.
```

please help me how to use or install through swift package manager

Comment: The SPM (Swift Package Manager) is a feature of Swift 3 (swift.org's releases).

Comment: @EricD can u please help about how to get connected with postgresql db from an ios app?

Comment: Nope, sorry, I know nothing about using PostgreSQL in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

use this [link](https://swift.org/getting-started/#using-the-package-manager) to understand the basics of SPM
for example: 
create a directory where you want to build your app with PostgreSQL library, 
go terminal and write

```
swift package init --type executable
```

to create basic starting project
use `Package.swift` to describe your targets/dependencies structure for the swift builder.

that's how your project's `Package.swift` file could look like with using only this `PostgreSQL` library:

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "YOURPROJECTNAME",
    products: [
        .executable(name: "YOURPROJECTNAME", targets: ["YOURPROJECTNAME"]),
        ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/stepanhruda/PostgreSQL-Swift.git", from: "0.0.1"),
        ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "YOURPROJECTNAME",
            dependencies: ["PostgreSQL"],
            path: "Sources"),
        ],
    swiftLanguageVersions: [.v4_2]
)
```

to deeper learn about SPM, use:

```
https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/tree/master/Documentation
```

notice also, there is a difference between versions of how you write your `Package.swift`, the way you write it called **PackageDescription API**.

after you create you Package.swift manifest, you can put your code into "Source library", and build it, using

```
swift build
```

to update your dependencies use:

```
swift package update
```

if you want to use Xcode as your IDE, generate xcodeproj file, using:

```
swift package generate-xcodeproj
```

also, notice you have re-create this file after every dependency added.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/adding_package_dependencies_to_your_app) that I used to install dependencies in my project.